# yum Install Docker on Centos | Reqires container-selinux libseccomp slirp4netns fuse-overlayfs error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, centos, centos7, yum

we are trying to install docker on our CentOS 7.5 according to https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-docker-centos-7 and some other similar guides and failing with following error. Can someone advise how to overcome it or provide alternative installation steps from his experience?

```
[root@I******1 ~]# yum install -y docker-ce
.....

**Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-20.10.8-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)** 

         **Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74**

**Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-20.10.8-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)**
           
         **Requires: libseccomp >= 2.3**

**Error: Package: containerd.io-1.4.9-3.1.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)**

           **Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74**

**Error: Package: docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.8-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)**

           **Requires: slirp4netns >= 0.4**

**Error: Package: docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.8-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)**
           **Requires: fuse-overlayfs >= 0.7**

**Error: Package: containerd.io-1.4.9-3.1.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)**

         **Requires: libseccomp**
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this. I am using your steps within a Docker container:

```
FROM quay.io/centos/centos:7

RUN yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2 && \
    yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo && \
    yum install -y docker-ce
```

All the dependencies that you have listed, such as `slirp4netns` and `libseccomp`,  are available in the default CentOS 7 repositories (`base`, `updates`, `extras`).